# Jar execution error for package structure

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I m trying to create a jar and execute it for the package structured java program. I m able to create jar but I m executing its 
throwing error.

**Folder Structure : Java_Example > pack > A.java**

```
package pack;  
public class A{  
  public void msg(){System.out.println("Hello");}  
}
```

**Folder Structure : Java_Example > mypack > B.java**

```
package mypack;  
import pack.*;  

class B{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   A obj = new A();  
   obj.msg();  
  }  
}
```

**Folder Structure : Java_Example > bin > Manifest.txt**

```
Mainfest-Version: 1.1
Main-Class: mypack.B
```

*Manifest file is present with line feeder*

Executing from Command Line

```
E:\Java_Example\bin>java -cp E:\Java_Example mypack.B
Hello
```

Creating Jar

```
E:\Java_Example\bin>jar cvf MyJar.jar Manifest.txt E:\Java_Example\pack\A.clas
E:\Java_Example\mypack\B.class
added manifest
adding: Manifest.txt(in = 60) (out= 61)(deflated -1%)
adding: Java_Example/pack/A.class(in = 376) (out= 268)(deflated 28%)
adding: Java_Example/mypack/B.class(in = 307) (out= 237)(deflated 22%)
```

Executing Jar

```
      E:\Java_Example\bin>jar -jar MyJar.jar
       Illegal option: j
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] f
iles ...
```

java -jar command execution

```
E:\Java_Example\bin>java -jar MyJar.jar
no main manifest attribute, in MyJar.jar
```

Trying execute Jar by giving main class

```
E:\Java_Example\bin>jar -cp MyJar.jar mypack.B
Illegal option: p
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] f
iles ...
```

jar -tf output

```
E:\Java_Example\bin>jar -tf MyJar.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest.txt
Java_Example/pack/A.class
Java_Example/mypack/B.class
```

Comment: the manifest file should be under `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, can you check the generated jar to see if this is the case?

Comment: Try `java -jar MyJar.jar`.

Comment: @RJB: can see MANIFEST.MF file created, I have edited question and added -tf output..

Comment: @LutzHorn: java -jar is also throwing an error, I have edited question and pasted command and its output

Comment: "no main manifest attribute" means there is no `Main-Class` in file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` - it is not the same as `Manifest.txt` (wrong location, wrong extension). Add either `--main-class=mypack.B` or `--manifest=Manifest.txt` when creating the jar. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/jar.html#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building the jar file wrong. Do it from the base folder, and add the `m` option to specify that you're listing the manifest file right after the jar file name (because `f` is before `m`).

```
E:\Java_Example>jar cvfm MyJar.jar bin\Manifest.txt pack\A.class mypack\B.class
added manifest
adding: pack/A.class(in = 376) (out= 268)(deflated 28%)
adding: mypack/B.class(in = 307) (out= 237)(deflated 22%)
```

As you can see, the class files are now correctly qualified, and it didn't say `adding: Manifest.txt` because that file is now the `manifest`.

Now you run it like this:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

If you want the jar file inside the bin folder, you'd of course just qualify that:

```
E:\Java_Example>jar cvfm bin\MyJar.jar bin\Manifest.txt pack\A.class mypack\B.class
E:\Java_Example>java -jar bin\MyJar.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a jar using the `jar` command, use `java` instead. For your edited question, the manifest is not in the right place. See the output of your jar extraction:

```
E:\Java_Example\bin>jar -tf MyJar.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest.txt
Java_Example/pack/A.class
Java_Example/mypack/B.class
```

You shouldn't have `Manifest.txt`, the manifest is `MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Edited question, jar -jar command is also throwing an error. Pasted error in question